# Transition of a large bucket to S3 Glacier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I want to move a 72 TB size bucket from S3 Standard to S3 Glacier.
I'm going to create a Lifecycle rule and set "Transition current versions of objects between storage classes" to 1 day.
I guess it won't be in one day because I'm not sure that AWS will handle this load and make the transition of 72 TB of data in one day.
Is any way to predict the timeline?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how long it would take to transition that data, but you should be mindful of potential cost coming from request charges especially if those 72TB are mostly smaller files: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/lifecycle-transition-general-considerations.html

Comment: Why does it matter? Cost? It will transition fairly quickly, but there's no way to know how long. You may think 72TB is a lot of data, but S3 might hold a zetabyte of data which makes 72TB a rounding error. Given your data is probably spread out across hundreds or thousands of physical drives, going to many a service that probably has a huge cache that then writes data to tape (guessing here), it won't take all that long.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  Previously we transitioned another 11TB-sized bucket with the same lifecycle rule, and AWS took about 3 days to transition it. 
So it mattered for me because I wished to be ready to answer this question if my management would ask it - @Tim
Anyway Tim, thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In this case it took 1 day** (or even less) to transition.
Applied Lifecycle rule to "Transition current versions of objects between storage classes" from S3 Standard to S3 Glacier and set 1 day.
**Bucket metrics: size - 73 TB; total number of objects - 6.5 M**.
The rule applied on Oct 6 at 9:30 am.
Checked bucket on Oct 7, at 7:00 am - all objects showed "Glacier" storage class.

Before I had **another case**:
The same Lifecycle rule mentioned above.
**Bucket metrics: size - 11 TB; total number of objects - 2.1 M**.
Transition took about 3 days (didn't note the exact time).

So based only on bucket size and objects count we can't predict.